# How to list column families in keyspace?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh

How can I get list of all column families in keyspace in Cassandra using CQL 3?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
cqlsh> select columnfamily_name from system.schema_columnfamilies where keyspace_name = 'test';

 columnfamily_name
-------------------
           commits
               foo
     has_all_types
      item_by_user
              test
             test2
      user_by_item

(7 rows)
```

Comment: As of Cassandra 3.0, this should be: `SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'test';`

Answer (score 39):

Or even more simply (if you are using cqlsh), switch over to your keyspace with `use` and then execute `describe tables`:

```
cqlsh> use products;
cqlsh:products> describe tables;

itemmaster    itemhierarchy         companyitemfavorites
testtable
```

Note: The [describe](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/describe_r.html) command is specific to cqlsh only.

Answer (score 11):

[CQL API](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html) supports both `TABLES` and `COLUMNFAMILIES`:

```
$ cqlsh
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACES;
cqlsh> USE keyspace_shaharma;
```

see column families,

```
cqlsh:keyspace_shaharma> DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILIES;
```

or

```
cqlsh:keyspace_shaharma> DESCRIBE TABLES;
```

Answer (score 2):

To list the column family or tables in the keyspace :

1. By using select Query:

   **SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name ='mydb';**
2. By selecting Keyspace and then we can list the tables available inside the keyspace :

   **use keyspace_name**
   **describe tables;**
3. By using Describe Keyword:

   **describe COLUMNFAMILIES;**